# How to return indices from javascript filter function (filtered based on values)?

Tags: javascript, filter

I want to do something that seems simple but I cannot figure it out.
I want to use the javascript function 'filter' to find values in an array greater than a value and then return the indices that correspond the those filtered values (or values in that indice range from another array.

```
arr1 = [1,3,7,9,11];
arr1 = [2,4,8,10,12];
arr1.filter(x => x > 7);
// returns: [9,11]
// desired return: [4,5] (indices from arr1 where values from arr1 that were filtered) and/or [10,12]  
// (values from arr2 where values from arr1 that were filtered)
```

I know the code is not right but I cannot figure out how to get desired result.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think one of those `arr1` should be `arr2`.  Given that, `arr1.filter(x => arr2[x] > 7);`

Comment: You can't do it with a `.filter` - the only thing `.filter` does is to reduce the amount of elements in the array, it doesn't transform them. You probably want `reduce` or a `map` to tuples (essentially tag values with their index) -> `filter` based on the data -> `map` back to indeces.

Comment: zeri298, yes you are correct, the second array is arr2, thanks

Comment: `filter` accepts a special type of function called [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)). Return type of a `predicate` is `Boolean` by definition which limits `filter` functionality to just filter elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map` in combination with `filter` to achieve this:

```
arr1.map((x, i) => [x,i]).filter(([x,i]) => x > 7).map(([x,i]) => i);
```

This maps the array to an array of pairs where the first element is the original number and the second is the original index. Then it filters the pairs by the first element of each pair before mapping it back to the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and do this in one run of the array by checking and transforming the data at once

```js
const arr1 = [1,3,7,9,11];

const result = arr1.reduce((acc, x, index) => acc.concat(x > 7 ? index : []), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
    var arr1 = [2,4,8,10,12];
        
    console.log(arr1.filter(x => x>7).map(m => arr1.indexOf(m)))
```

returns [2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `map` call and `indexOf`

PS: If there are duplicate values, indexOf return only first occurrence.

Alternatively, if you are not particular about `filter`, you can use `reduce` which can done with one iteration.

```js
const arr1 = [1,3,7,9,11];
const arr2 = [2,4,8,10,12];

const filter = arr => arr.filter(x => x > 7).map(x => arr.indexOf(x));

console.log(filter(arr1))
console.log(filter(arr2))

const filter2 = arr => arr.reduce((acc, x, i) => (x > 7 && acc.push(i), acc), []);
console.log(filter2(arr1))
console.log(filter2(arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method would be to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Here I'm using [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to optionally add the index to the array used as the initial value of the accumulator.

```js
var arr1 = [1,3,7,9,11];
var indexes = arr1.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => acc = cur > 7 ? [...acc, idx] : acc, []);
console.log(indexes);
```